# How to create blank console in R?

Tags: r, console, rstudio

How can I wipe my R Studio console clean and start over without closing out of the application and reopening it?

Thanks

Comment: With a lint-free cloth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use clear console menu command or short cut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

[image: Image Menu]

Answer (score 2):

You can clear the console by typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: The escape-letter equivalencies are available at `?Quotes`